# Force.com: User vs Account vs Role vs Profile vs Owner

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I'm starting out with force.com development, and I'm currently a little hazy about what the above terms all mean.  Could someone give an overview, and if possible explain how permissions are defined on each one (if at all)?

Comment: As a general comment, I would also recommend working through the Fundamentals workbook, which took me a while to find out about. It explains things really well.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/index.htm

Answer (score 35, accepted):

- **User**: a user who can login to Salesforce. Also includes customer and partner portal users.
- **Account**: a business account, which usually represents a company and usually has child contacts (i.e. people in the company)
- **Role**: a hierarchical group users in an organization that is used as part of the sharing model. Users in higher roles have rights to see the records owned by users in lower roles (assuming their Profile allows it). Users do not have to belong to a role.
- **Profile**: a collection of permissions and access rights for a user including CRUD permissions. A user must belong to exactly one profile. Also see about Permission Sets, which are a many-to-many relationship with users and augment profiles.
- **Owner**: A user or group (queue) that owns a record. Record ownership along with the role hierarchy (and a few other things) control who can see the record.

To put it all together, you could say something like:

*John Doe* is a salesperson for *ABC, Inc*, and is a **user** in their **organization**. He  is the **owner** of the *Acme* **account**. He has the *Salesperson* **role**, which is subordinate to the *Sales Manager* **role**, so his manager can see all his records. He has the *Standard User* **profile**, so he cannot perform administrative functions in Salesforce.

I'd also recommend that you take a look at the [API doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm), which explains all the entities and has relationship diagrams.